# How else but aeson?

Tags: parsing, haskell, aeson

`aeson` seems to take a somewhat simple-minded approach to parsing JSON: it parses a top-level JSON value (an object or array) to its own fixed representation and then offers facilities to help users convert that representation to their own. This approach works pretty well when JSON objects and arrays are small. When they're very large, things start to fall apart, because user code can't do anything until JSON values are completely read and parsed. This seems particularly unfortunate since JSON seems to be designed for recursive descent parsers— it seems like it should be fairly simple to allow user code to step in and say how each piece should be parsed. Is there a deep reason `aeson` and the earlier `json` work this way, or should I try to make a new library for more flexible JSON parsing?

Comment: Have you tried stream-based parsers, like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-stream ?

Comment: You can parse to something more "freeform" and then access random properties using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-lens

Comment: @Yuuri, could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json-stream](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-stream) is a stream based parser. This is a bit out of date (2015), but they took the benchmarks from `aeson` and compared the two libraries: [aeson and json-stream performance comparison](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3j25zp/jsonstream_incremental_json_streaming_parser_any/). There is one case where `json-stream` is significantly worse than `aeson`.

If you just want a faster `aeson` (not streaming), [haskell-sajson](https://github.com/kccqzy/haskell-sajson) looks interesting. It wraps a performant C++ library in Haskell and returns `Value` from `aeson`.